# Checkbox toggle within <p-dialog> not working manually through UI

Tags: angular, checkbox, primeng, primeng-dialog

I am working on adding checkboxes inside 'p-dialog' part of primeng package.
However,I am stuck at a UI issue, when I try to check uncheck the checkbox manually from UI,it doesnt work also the change or click event does not fire for the same. Posting below part of code related of checkbox.
Could someone suggest as to what needs to be fixed to get it working.

Html code

```
<p-dialog modal="modal" width="600" [responsive]="true" [closable]="false">
    <p-header>
      <span>Dialog</span>
    </p-header>
    <input type="checkbox" [name]="chkMyself" [id]="chkMyself" (change)="toggleVal($event)" >             
              <label for="chkMyself">Myself</label>
</p-dialog>
```

Component code

```
import { Component,  Output,ViewChild, EventEmitter, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Dialog } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './app-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class AppDialogComponent {
  
  @ViewChild(Dialog) public theDialog: Dialog;
  public dialogTitle: string;
  public chkMyself: boolean = false; 

  constructor( ) {       
    }
    private _display: boolean = false;

    get Display(): boolean {
        return this._display;
    }
    set Display(val: boolean) {
        this._display = val;
        if(val){
          this.show("Dialog Test");
        }       
    }
     
  public toggleVal(event): void {
   debugger
    this.chkMyself = !event.target.checked;
}
 
  public show(dialogTitle: string)
  {    
     this.dialogTitle = dialogTitle;  
      this.theDialog.visible=true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solution that worked for me
Tried below and it worked for me.
<input type="checkbox" name="chkMyself" id="chkMyself" (change)="toggleVal($event)" >
Myself

Answer (score 1):

The NAME attribute is used in the HTTP request sent by browser to the server as a variable name and it is associated with the data contained in the value attribute.
The ID of a form Element has nothing to do with it. It's just an identification and has nothing to do with the data contained within the element.